# How to style {Switch} component from react-router-dom? I tried wrapping it with <div> and does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

[image]

I have this code below and tried to change the map component styling. However, it looks like it is from Switch component. How can i make the screen fit into 'root' element here? I used  or container from MUI and other things to adjust the size but none of them work.

```
   <MainWrapper>
        <Visible when={isLogged}>
          <LeftPanel />
        </Visible>
        <div style={{width: '100%'}}>
        <Visible when={isLogged}>
          <Navbar />
        </Visible>
        <div style={{height: '100hv'}}>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/map'
            component={MapPage}
            isLogged={isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/profile'
            component={UserProfile}
            isLogged={isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/login'
            component={Login}
            isLogged={!isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/map'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/registration'
            component={Registration}
            isLogged={!isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/map'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/'
            component={{}}
            isLogged={false}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </div>
      </MainWrapper>
    );
  }
}

const MainWrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
`;
```

Comment: `Switch` is a container, there isn't much of a visual aspect to it. It looks like one of the components being rendered on a route isn't 100% height of parent. Can you provide a running codesandbox that repros this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was going to use codesendbox but then there are so many codes that I need to adjust. But, when I remove all the <div>s then it comes normal besides my navbar is not on the top of the other components but they are just left side of the maps. That shifting everything to the right. I've been trying to add <App Bar> Component from MUI.

Comment: Drew, you were right! there was one component did not have 100vh. I feel so stupid now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be related to a type:

```
<div style={{height: '100hv'}}>
```

it should be `vh` (as viewport height) instead of `hv`:

```
<div style={{height: '100vh'}}>
```

since you're using MainWrapper as flex-box the issue may be solved if you set `flex: 1` for child div:

```
<div style={{height: '100hv', flex: 1}}>
```

`flex: 1` means fit the parent.

Comment: Oh, this is a great catch, but is rather a typo on OP's part.

Comment: i was hoping that this was it but it wasn't :/ I am so lost. It works find if I remove my Nav + side bar + div. Then it covers 100% width and height.

Comment: check out my eddited answer

Comment: Hi there, Drew was right in the beginning! I check other components and fix their heights to 100vh and now it works! Now, I have my App Bar overlapping my other components. Yeah haha one problem after another! Love coding